# Ember Data - hasMany/belongsTo with different model than default

Tags: ember.js, associations, ember-data, belongs-to

In Ember Data, how do you define a belongsTo/hasMany association that uses a different model or foreign key than what would be chosen by default?

For example, I have an `App.Item` that belongsTo an `App.User` models, but I want to access the user via the `owner` attribute:

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  owner: DS.belongsTo('App.User'),
});

item.get('owner'); // should be an App.User

// And the data from the server looks like:
{
  owner: 2, //id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify custom primary keys on the adapter. These need to be set before the store is created.

```
App.Adapter.map('App.User', {
  primaryKey: 'owner'
});
```